# jquery ajax triggering another jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have drop-downs for:
1. manufacturer
2. products
3. colours

Manufacturer drop is fetched with page.
When I select manuf. from it Ajax appends #2.
When I select product, Ajax appends #3

Problem is, that #3 is is not being fetched.
I appreciate a hint.

Code I use:

```
    $("#manuf").change(function(){
        var manuf_id = $("#manuf").val();
        $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "ajax_product_preload.php", 
                data: "manuf_id=" + manuf_id,
                success: function(data){
                    $("#prod_div").hide().html(data).fadeIn(); 
                    }
              });       
        });
```

Code for colour is similar, just a IDs, php file and data string change.
Php files are simple db queries and dropdowns, so posting them would be a waste of SO hdd .. I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are binding the change handler for #2's content before it loads, right? If that is the case, you can likely fix your problem using [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
    $("#prod").live('change', function(){
```

assuming that `#prod` is the `select` element that contains the list of products.

Comment: thank you - I knew it was something simple - it just proves how big of a "newb" I am as far as JQ is concerned, but I'm learning ... thank you again ;)